# MySQL Performance Tuning - server 128 M

Tags: mysql, performance

i have a server 128 M with mysql installed.can you please help me to configure my server and increase server performance.

- i use wordpress 3.5
- all of my tables is MyIsam

this is my first config:

```
[mysqld]

tmp_table_size=4M
query_cache_size=2M
max_heap_table_size = 8M
query_cache_limit=1M
query_cache_size=4M
max_connections=55
skip-locking
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 4
sort_buffer_size = 64K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
net_buffer_length = 2K
thread_stack = 128K
table_open_cache = 8
max_binlog_cache_size = 1M
max_seeks_for_key = 2M
max_write_lock_count = 512K
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 1M
innodb_file_per_table=1
query_cache_type = 1
thread_cache_size=2
key_buffer=12M 
thread_concurrency=2
########################
##Configuration Innodb##
##Uncomment the next line to disable Innodb

#skip-innodb

innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M

innodb_log_file_size            = 10M
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 4M

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
```

thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you saying due to the fact you only have 128M of mem on your mysql server that you want to fine tune this configuration file as much as possible (i.e. useful notes on what can be decreased and why)?
I have a 512M mem machine with an Innodb mysql db and have not touched any of these settings and it runs absolutely fine.

Comment: yes i have only 128M of mem and i want tune this config as much as possible,

Comment: Uncomment the `skip-innodb` if you're not using InnoDB tables. This example might be a good place to start: http://fts.ifac.cnr.it/cgi-bin/dwww/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0/examples/my-medium.cnf.gz

Answer (score 1):

I think the most valuable thing you could do to improve your server's performance is to go buy a good book, read it, read some articlaes on the internet, and go on a training course - or pay someone who knows what they're doing to help you.

You've not provided a whole load of information that would inform any tuning exercise - you've not said what aspect of the performance you want to improve is.

128M is a **tiny** amount of memory - implying a virtual server - further, there is no rational reason to rent out a virtual server then only run mysql on it (OK there might be some edge cases - but you didn't say) which implies it's doing a lot of other stuff too (like webserving).

You need to learn how to ask the right questions in the right way.

Comment: in tuning there is one aspect is the time of response, tha s why i search

Comment: I agree that 128M is too small, I would say 512M is the minimum you should really go for if it is going to be doing anything which requires it perform well (or at least ok).

Comment: yes I have not learned how the tuning work but i have lerned that if I dont have an answered i silent

Comment: @user1010600: time of response is at least three things: lock time, latency, time for complete result set - and that's only looking at the database - the amount of memory, CPU and disk I/O the DBMS uses to resolve the query will affect other things running on the box - like a webserver. You need to learn how to ask the right questions in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

**innodb_buffer_pool_size** is by far the largest BUT is the most important option so unless you want a very under performing innodb DB I would leave that one alone.

Have you run the db so see how it performs?

128M could work (but still is not advised) if you have the queries fine tuned (run **explain** to profile them and add **indexes** where appropriate).

I have not heard of anyone significantly improving performance of a mysql db by JUST reducing values in the config. Often this can lead to decreased performance.

Comment: thanks Craig, i use wordpresse and all of my table is MyIsam

Comment: thats confusing as the config reads the db engine as innodb